Python and Swift integration with PythonKit crashes on build
I got python all embedded with my project using PythonKit in Xcode and my python files are built as bundle resources so everything is working when I archive and then export as copy build. It loads python from the resources and then loads my scripts.
Big problem though is whenever I send the app to another computer to test it, it crashes immediately upon opening with this error:
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Filex [27455]
Path:                  /private/var/folders/*/Filex.app/Contents/MacOS/Filex
Identifier:            com.scorpionstudios.Filex
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-06-29 13:55:12.8411 -0700
OS Version:            macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     8.5 (21P5077)
Anonymous UUID:        0BCB58F4-9F99-4BF4-18CD-32398D822138

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2CD8D2B8-6C7E-4A0A-9B76-EFCB335AD370

Time Awake Since Boot: 1200000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       121 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [27455]

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib                    0x7ff81796cd9f _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 351
1   libswiftCore.dylib                    0x7ff8179c4a48 swift_unexpectedError + 840
2   Filex                                    0x10442930f PythonInterface.import(_:) + 111
3   Filex                                    0x1044238e4 PythonAPI.init() + 5796
4   Filex                                    0x104422231 PythonAPI.__allocating_init() + 33
5   Filex                                    0x1043f5918 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in variable initialization expression of Main._pythonAPI + 24
6   SwiftUI                               0x7ff9148f840f 0x7ff913d73000 + 12080143

I can't figure out why this is happening??? If I comment out this line of code the error doesn't happen:
var main : PythonObject = Python.import("main")

"main" is a file module (main.py) that is is included in the apps bundle resources and I added the resource path Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Resources", ofType: nil). It works on my computer when I build it so I don't know why it doesn't work on others??? Any ideas?
